# Finding out Windows System Info For a Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, windows-server-2008

How do I find out a Windows system's CPU & RAM usage/max capacity using a Ruby script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a gem like [Ruby-WMI](http://ruby-wmi.rubyforge.org/) and then pull out the data for the relevant device.

Comment: Thanks @ScottKShea! Is there any update gem for this? The last update seems to be 2008. If not, this is a great start nonetheless.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the most prevalent. Hopefully it is not too out of date.

Comment: you might have the answer to another question of mine as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282982/keeping-track-of-windows-processes - I'd appreciate it if you took a look, thanks!